# AJAX Update Entry (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: templating, ajax

I'm trying to update an entry on the front end with a click and without a form. I'm a bit new with AJAX but would love to simply put a new title for the entry that the button relates to. I'm currently getting `500 Internal Server Errors` when trying.

```
{% for entry in currentUserSubmissions %}
  {{ entry.title }}
  {{ entry.submissionUrl }}
  <a class="btn btn-approve btn-primary" data-id="{{ entry.id }}">Approve</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my AJAX

```
{% js at endBody %}

  $('.btn-approve').on('click', function() {

    var entryId = $(this).data('id');
    var data = {
        value: entryId,
        name: 'entryId',
        title: 'hello test'
    };
    var tokenName = '{{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName }}';
    data[tokenName] = '{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken }}';

    // send ajax request
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/actions/entries/saveEntry",
      data: data,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('success', data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log('error', data);
      }
    });
  });
{% endjs %}
```

> /actions/entries/saveEntry 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What does your logs say? `storage/logs/web.log`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the url from "/actions/entries/saveEntry" to "/actions/entries/save-entry"